# Assignment for .loc() when looping through stratified indexes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I just started learning machine learning and am stuck on understanding this piece of code. I understand how the stratified shift class method generates a set of training and test indices to loop through. What I am confused about is how strat_train_set contains more than a single value. I tried running the code and it is evident that both variables contains collections but there is no increment or add function. Wouldn't each run through the loop replace the current record with the new one thus leading to strat_train_set and strat_test_set containing a single record of the dateset rather than multiple values.

```
for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
      strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
      strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop is delivering an entire fold on each iteration.  `train_index` and `test_index` are collections of index values themselves that are then used as multi-value indices into the housing `DF` via `.loc()` - a vectorized operation.  It would then follow that `strat_train_set` and `strat_test_set` are also collections.

Make sense?

Comment: I think I understand so the runs of the loop would look like: 0:1 on the first loop 0:2 on the second loop and so on. If that is the case is there a need to loop isn't it possible to get the start and end index straight off the bat.

Comment: Not really. For example, with a 10 fold split, you get 1/10th of each set on each iteration.  The idea is that you process each fold on each iteration.